# How to assign the order of partition of data by time in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Suppose, I have a dataframe like below:

```
simpleData = (("U1", "cd1dd155-ccd8-4b8c-bea7-571359e35fed", 1655605947), \
    ("U1", "7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb", 1655777060),  \
    ("U1", "7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb", 1655777062),
    ("U1", "c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7", 1656209951),   \
    ("U1", "c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7", 1656209952),  \
    ("U1", "c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7", 1656209999),    \
  )
 
columns= ["UID", "Sess", "Time"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+------------------------------------+----------+
|UID|Sess                                |Time      |
+---+------------------------------------+----------+
|U1 |cd1dd155-ccd8-4b8c-bea7-571359e35fed|1655605947|
|U1 |7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb|1655777060|
|U1 |7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb|1655777062|
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209951|
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209952|
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209999|
+---+------------------------------------+----------+
```

And I am assigning a rank of rows within a window partition as

```
df2 = df.withColumn("sess_2", F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('UID', 'Sess')))
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

I get the following output:

```
+---+------------------------------------+----------+------+
|UID|Sess                                |Time      |sess_2|
+---+------------------------------------+----------+------+
|U1 |7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb|1655777060|1     |
|U1 |7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb|1655777062|1     |
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209951|2     |
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209952|2     |
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209999|2     |
|U1 |cd1dd155-ccd8-4b8c-bea7-571359e35fed|1655605947|3     |
+---+------------------------------------+----------+------+
```

whereas I am expecting it to be

```
+---+------------------------------------+----------+------+
|UID|Sess                                |Time      |sess_2|
+---+------------------------------------+----------+------+
|U1 |cd1dd155-ccd8-4b8c-bea7-571359e35fed|1655605947|1     |
|U1 |7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb|1655777060|2     |
|U1 |7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb|1655777062|2     |
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209951|3     |
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209952|3     |
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209999|3     |
+---+------------------------------------+----------+------+
```

How do I assign the correct *sess_2* for each partition with *UID* and *sess* ordered by time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, first you will need to find the session start time per `UID` and `Sess` and order your Window based on this.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

simpleData = (("U1", "cd1dd155-ccd8-4b8c-bea7-571359e35fed", 1655605947), \
    ("U1", "7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb", 1655777060),  \
    ("U1", "7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb", 1655777062),
    ("U1", "c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7", 1656209951),   \
    ("U1", "c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7", 1656209952),  \
    ("U1", "c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7", 1656209999),    \
  )
 
columns= ["UID", "Sess", "Time"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)

# per UID and Sess find when the session started and add Sess to the end to resolve duplicates when multiple sessions can start at the same time.
sess_ws = Window.partitionBy("UID", "Sess")
df_with_session_start = df.withColumn("session_start", F.concat(F.min("time").over(sess_ws), F.col("Sess")))

df2 = df_with_session_start.withColumn("sess_2", F.dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("UID").orderBy("session_start")))
df2.show(truncate=False)

"""
+---+------------------------------------+----------+------+
|UID|Sess                                |Time      |sess_2|
+---+------------------------------------+----------+------+
|U1 |cd1dd155-ccd8-4b8c-bea7-571359e35fed|1655605947|1     |
|U1 |7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb|1655777060|2     |
|U1 |7f20182f-8c82-4c70-8213-f7889cfdd5eb|1655777062|2     |
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209951|3     |
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209952|3     |
|U1 |c4d5a218-d61d-4e9a-b1ea-646f676c4cb7|1656209999|3     |
+---+------------------------------------+----------+------+
"""
```